# Selenium Grids jars compatibility with Firefox versions

Tags: automation, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on Selenium Grid to automate cross platform functionality and using selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar. When i am using Firefox 22.0 it is working properly but not supporting Firefox 27.0. I have tried with selenium jar version 2.37 ,2.38 and 2.39 but the issue still exists. Which version of selenium-server-standalone jar supports latest Firefox versions ?

Comment: Well what issue? You've said you get an issue but not explained what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying on Firefox 27.0. Selenium grid doesnt support it. I just tried on other browser versions and it's working.